# Will Righteous Cause trigger with tapped and attacking tokens

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Will i gain life if someone is attacking and they create a tapped and attack token

Answer (score 5):

### No.

The relevant trigger for the ability is "whenever a creature attacks", which is defined as declaring a creature as an attacker during the Declare Attackers step. Creature tokens which get put onto the battlefield "tapped and attacking" are never actually declared attackers (or get tapped for that matter) - at the time they are created, they are already attacking and tapped.

Rules for declaring attackers are defined in [CR508](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr508/), in particular sections .3 and .4 (emphasis mine).

> 508.3a An ability that reads “Whenever [a creature] attacks, . . .” triggers if that creature is declared as an attacker. Similarly,
> “Whenever [a creature] attacks [a player or planeswalker], . . .”
> triggers if that creature is declared as an attacker attacking that
> player or planeswalker. **Such abilities won’t trigger if a creature is
> put onto the battlefield attacking.**
>
> 508.4 ...[creatures put onto the battlefield attacking]
> are “attacking” but, for the purposes of trigger events and effects,
> they never “attacked.”

Comment: Cuz the judge at my card shop said yes cuz the card reads when ever a creature attacks i gain 1 doesnt matter about declare and orim prayer says when ever a creature attacks you as in declared as a attack on u u gain 1 from prayer

Comment: @KneelBe4Zodd the judge was wrong. Refer them to CR 508.3a; the creature was never declared as an attacker.

Comment: I see that but that says when attack you, that happens… my card it when a creature attacks, you gain 1

Comment: @KneelBe4Zodd There's no difference. "When a creature attacks" occurs at the time it's declared an attacker. You can't just choose to set off a "when attacks" trigger at any time while a creature is attacking.

Comment: @KneelBe4Zodd I'm not sure what point you're making: your creature has not attacked _as defined by the rules of the game_.

Comment: @KneelBe4Zodd Judge here, whoever was judging your event was wrong. An attack trigger happens when a creature is declared as an attacker. A creature put in tapped and attacking is never declared as an attacker and thus does not trigger any attack triggers.